# How to use useState with an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to use useState with an object? This is not the same as other similar questions. My code below gives strange error...

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState({data: 'something'});

    return (
         <h1>Data: {data}</h1>
    );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/usestate-with-an-object-m176t?file=/src/App.js:0-167

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is not at the `useState`.
Your problem happens when you try to render the `{data}`, because is an object. You need to render a property.

In this case, your data object is:

```
{
  data: 'something'
}
```

To render the value, you should:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState({data: 'something'});

    return (
         <h1>Data: {data.data}</h1>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You **can not pass objects** as children in React**.

**Please note** that you are passing an object `<h1>Data: {data}</h1>`, the **data is an object** that has a data property

**Solution**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState({data: 'something'});

    return (
         <h1>Data: {data.data}</h1>
    );
}
```